# getUpdates Telegram Bot API

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть группа, в которой 3 администратора:
Я и два бота.
Когда я пересылаю в группу сообщение, то в getUpdates у одного бота видно:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":985498439,
"message":{"message_id":6,"from":{"id":***,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"***","last_name":"***","username":"***"},"chat":{"id":***,"title":"***","type":"group","all_members_are_administrators":false},"date":1557316578,"forward_from":{"id":***,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"***","last_name":"***","username":"***"},"forward_date":1557316555,"text":"9"}}]}
```

Однако когда другой бот пересылает сообщение в группу, то в getUpdates у первого бота ничего не появляется. Оба бота администраторы и у обоих

```
Privacy mode = false
```

В чем может быть проблема?

P.S Когда один бот пишет, а не пересылает все отображается в getUpdates у другого бота
P.P.S Когда один бот пишет вместе с разметкой(reply_markup) то в getUpdates у другого снова ничего не видно

Answer (score 1):

Один бот не может видеть сообщения другого бота, пока на них не ответит юзер, для использования каких-либо функций первого бота. Например, установка триггера на сообщение другого бота реплаем позволит первому боту увидеть нужное сообщение от второго.

Выключение режима приватности позволяет боту видеть все сообщения кроме

1. Сообщений других ботов
2. Команд для других ботов /help@other_bot

Comment: подтверждаю, раньше кстати мог бот видеть бота, но потом они убрали это, а то боты зацикливали друг друга